# Accompanying object for trait in Scala

Tags: scala

I try to write general `apply` method to serve as a factory method for child classes. What I came up with is following:

```
trait A 

object A {
    def apply[T <: A](someParam: String): T {
        new T()
    }
}

class B private extends A 
class C private extends A
```

So one can create new B or C instance:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    A[B]("test")
}
```

Is it acceptable that trait has an accompanying object?Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: As far as companion object for a trait goes, it's fine. As to your other question ... Did you try to compile your code?

Comment: You probably want `sealed trait A` and http://engineering.monsanto.com/2016/01/11/algebraic-data-types/

Comment: @Reactormonk `C` and `B` are not in same file so I am not sure about `sealed trait` but I will check that link.

Comment: @Dima This is just example, not sure how it will compile.

Comment: @gorros it won't

Comment: ... what problem do you want to solve? This looks like Java code, not Scala.

Comment: @Reactormonk I just want to have factory method for each class `C`  and `B` . I can write accompanying class for each of them, and implement `apply`. But that results in code repetition. And since I am learning scala,I want to try different approaches.

Comment: @gorros "Factory method" isn't something you need in Scala. A lot of patterns in Java are required because of the shortcomings of the language. Please tell us the overarching problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Reactormonk Basically, I want to control creation of class instances. Thus I use `apply` of accompanying object. But this results in a lot of repetition since I have similar classes. Hope this makes my goal more clear.

Comment: @gorros https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8I19uA-wGY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could:

```
  trait A

  object A {
    def apply[T <: A ](someParam: String) (implicit ev: ClassTag[T]): T ={
      ev.runtimeClass.newInstance().asInstanceOf[T]
    }
  }
```

But its not very useful with varying constructor's for each sub class

```
  sealed trait A

  object A {
    def apply[T <: A](someParam: String)(implicit ev: T): T = {
      ev
    }
  }

  class B(n: Int) extends A    
  class C(n: String) extends A

  object B {
    implicit def defaultCons: B = new B(1)
  }

  object C {
    implicit def defaultCons: C = new C("hi")
  }
```

Or you could also go via combination of `ClassTag` approach with pattern match based on the class instead of using reflection for instantiation.

Comment: Thanks @Jatin. It looks like what I was looking for. I will try this approach and mark the answer if it match my needs. I am not familiar with `ClassTag` but I came across it couple of time. Ca you provide a link to a resource with more details on it?

Comment: You answer works, but probably I will try to go another way. Thanks.